# chartクラスでグラフを出力する際の描画速度の効率化

Tags: c#

chartクラスで作成した描画する際、通常の設定では表示できない線の種類がある且つ出力先によってDPIが異なり、描画時、以下処理にてChartGraphicsをカスタムした線、解像度を修正してから出力しております。

しかし、出力あたって、現状以下の課題がございます。

- グラフの数だけ処理を行う必要があるため、数が多い場合、処理に時間が掛かっている
- PDFなどで出力した際、容量が大きくなる

出力速度と容量を改善したいのですが、何か良い方法はありますでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

**現状のコード:**

```
try {

    ChartGraphics cg = e.ChartGraphics;

    if((e.ChartElement is Series)) {

        RectangleF backup = cg.Graphics.ClipBounds;

        float basex = 0;
        float basey = 2005;
        float baseWidth = 4107;
        float baseHeight = 3543;
        int baseDpi = 600;

        float calcDpi = baseDpi / cg.Graphics.DpiX;

        RectangleF clipRect = new RectangleF(basex / calcDpi, basey / calcDpi, baseWidth / calcDpi, baseHeight / calcDpi);

        cg.Graphics.SetClip(clipRect);
        foreach(Series s in e.Chart.Series) {
            if(e.ChartElement == s) {
                if(s.BorderDashStyle != ChartDashStyle.Solid) {
                    s.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;

                    Color penColor = s.BorderColor;
                    int borderWidth = s.BorderWidth;
                    s.BorderWidth = 0;

                    string borderStyleListValue = "";
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in borderStyleList) {
                        if(kvp.Key == s.Name) {
                            borderStyleListValue = kvp.Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Pen blackPen = new Pen(penColor, borderWidth);

                    switch(borderStyleListValue) {
                        case "2":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Long_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.One_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Two_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Short_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Short_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    int maxCount = 27;
                    for(int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count - 1; i++) {
                        if(maxCount >= s.Points[i + 1].XValue) {
                            System.Drawing.PointF pos = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
                            pos.X = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis(s.ChartArea, AxisName.X, s.Points[i].XValue);
                            pos.Y = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis(s.ChartArea, AxisName.Y, s.Points[i].YValues[0]);

                            System.Drawing.PointF pos2 = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
                            pos2.X = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis(s.ChartArea, AxisName.X, s.Points[i + 1].XValue);
                            pos2.Y = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis(s.ChartArea, AxisName.Y, s.Points[i + 1].YValues[0]);

                            pos = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos);
                            pos2 = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos2);

                            cg.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, pos.X, pos.Y, pos2.X, pos2.Y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cg.Graphics.SetClip(backup);
    } else if((e.ChartElement is LegendCell)) {

        Legend col = e.Chart.Legends[0];
        int count = 0;
        foreach(LegendItem item in col.CustomItems) {

            LegendCell cell = item.Cells[1];
            if(e.ChartElement == cell) {
                if(cell.LegendItem.BorderDashStyle != ChartDashStyle.Solid) {
                    cell.LegendItem.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;

                    Color penColor = cell.LegendItem.Color;
                    int borderWidth = cell.LegendItem.BorderWidth;

                    Pen blackPen = new Pen(penColor, borderWidth);

                    string borderStyleListValue = "";
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in borderStyleList) {
                        if(kvp.Key == cell.LegendItem.Name) {
                            borderStyleListValue = kvp.Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    switch(borderStyleListValue) {
                        case "2":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Long_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.One_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Two_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Short_Dash;
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            blackPen.DashPattern = Const.Border_Dash_Point.Short_Point_Dash;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    PointF pos = PointF.Empty;
                    PointF pos2 = PointF.Empty;

                    pos.X = e.Position.X;
                    pos.Y = e.Position.Y + e.Position.Height / 2;
                    pos2.X = e.Position.X + e.Position.Width;
                    pos2.Y = e.Position.Y + e.Position.Height / 2;

                    pos = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos);
                    pos2 = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos2);

                    cg.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, pos.X, pos.Y, pos2.X, pos2.Y);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }

    } else {
        return;
    }

}catch(Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("例外");
}
```

Comment: あなたの言う「chartクラス」って何ですか？

Comment: .Net Frameworkにて用意されているSystem.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Chartingになります

Comment: ちなみにどんな高速化の手段が有って、既に適用済みとか試したが効果が無い/少ないとかの情報はあるのでしょうか？ 関連するか不明ですが検索するとこんな記事が見つかります。[c# Chartコントロール　大量プロットでスクロールするチャートの高速化](https://qiita.com/twentyfourhours/items/c31922ffe94649cd3a00), [【C#】手動ダブルバッファによる高速描画](https://imagingsolution.net/program/csharp/bufferedgraphicscontext/), [C#で高速にビットマップ画像を描く方法](http://nahitafu.cocolog-nifty.com/nahitafu/2020/05/post-97f6c8.html), [C#の高速化テクニックを伝授します！](https://www.fenet.jp/dotnet/column/language/5134/), [C#プログラマのための.NETアプリケーション最適化技法](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798131795)